# i installed FreeRADIUS , Mysql inside docker Container

Tags: docker, freeradius

I installed FreeRADIUS , Mysql inside docker Container 
I exposed ports 1812 , 1813 , 3306 outside  .
I imported Database to mysql .
I inserted this rows to databases

```
INSERT INTO nas VALUES (NULL , '0.0.0.0/0', 'myNAS', 'other', NULL , 'mysecret', NULL , NULL , 'RADIUS Client');

INSERT INTO radcheck (username, attribute, op, value) VALUES ('thisuser', 'User-Password', ':=', 'thispassword');

INSERT INTO radusergroup (username, groupname, priority) VALUES ('thisuser', 'thisgroup', '1');

INSERT INTO radgroupreply (groupname, attribute, op, value) VALUES ('thisgroup', 'Service-Type', ':=', 'Framed-User'), ('thisgroup', 'Framed-Protocol', ':=', 'PPP'), ('thisgroup', 'Framed-Compression', ':=', 'Van-Jacobsen-TCP-IP');
```

and i stopped freeradius ==> service freeradius stop
and iam using debug mode ==> freeradius -X
And when using this Command in another terminal for the same container  ==> radtest thisuser thispassword 127.0.0.1 0 mysecret

Output: Server Accepted the request

But When the previous Command in another machine

Server does not see the request and output in the other machine is " No response "

Notes in the IN etc IN freeradius IN radiusd.conf file :

```
listen {
type = auth
ipaddr = *
port = 0 }

listen {
ipaddr = *
port = 0
type = acct }
```

How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this Issue by expose Ports in UDP Protocol  -p 1813:1813/udp -p 1812:1812/udp

Answer (score 2):

Adding the rows to the sql database is insufficient.  You need to configure your sql instance in `mods-available/sql` to match your local database, uncomment `read_clients` in `mods-available/sql`, and list the sql module in the instantiate section in `radiusd.conf` to ensure it's loaded if it's not referenced elsewhere in one of the virtual servers.

After making these changes, restart the server.  The SQL module should then read the clients list in on startup.  Check the debug output `freeradius -X` to ensure the SQL module can connect to your database, and read the NAS entries in successfully.

The reason why your local connections work is because there's a client entry included for localhost in the `clients.conf` file that ships with the server.

Comment: Thank U Sir ,  i fixed this issue by expose ports in UDP Protocol 
-p 1813:1813/udp -p 1812:1812/udp

Comment: and your answer is Correct Sir :D